# Grant MySQL permissions on current database?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-grant

I can grant permissions with a static database name in the `GRANT` statement.

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT ON database_name.table_name TO 'username'@'localhost';
```

Is there a way to dynamically set the database name in a `GRANT` statement so that the grant is for whichever happens to be the current database?

```
USE database_name;
GRANT SELECT,INSERT ON <what goes here?>.table_name TO 'username'@'localhost';
```

Comment: the aim of `USE databasename;` instruction atop your script is precisely to specify the default database and to not have to prefix all your objects with the database name, so just do ...`ON table_name TO`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to specify anything. If no database is specified, MySQL will assume the `default database`, which is set when you `USE database_name`. From the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/use.html):

> The USE db_name statement tells MySQL to use the db_name database as the default (current) database for subsequent statements.

And from the section on [`GRANT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html):

> If you specify tbl_name rather than db_name.tbl_name, the statement applies to tbl_name in the default database.

So you can just use

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT ON table_name TO 'username'@'localhost';
```

Comment: Well how about that?! Thanks!!